# Adding custom SOAPHeader in C# for a web service call

Tags: c#, soapheader

I am trying to add a custom soap header information in c# before calling a web service. I am using SOAP Header class to get this done. I could do this partly but not completely the way I need it. Here is how I need the soap header to look like

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Header>
      <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <UsernameToken>
         <Username>USERID</Username>
         <Password>PASSWORD</Password>
        </UsernameToken>    
      </Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
   ...
```

I am able to add soap header as below

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Header>
      <UsernameToken xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <Username>UserID</Username>
         <Password>Test</Password>
      </UsernameToken>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
```

What I am not able to do is add the "Security" elements which wraps the "UsernameToken" as in the first sample. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This link [adding soap header](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/560786-how-add-soap-header-soap-message) worked for me.  I am calling a SOAP 1.1 service that I did not write and have no control over.  Am using VS 2012 and added the service as a web reference in my project.  Hope this helps

I followed the steps 1-5 from J. Dudgeon's post towards the bottom of the thread.

Here's some sample code (this would be in a separate .cs file):

```
namespace SAME_NAMESPACE_AS_PROXY_CLASS
{
    // This is needed since the web service must have the username and pwd passed in a custom SOAP header, apparently
    public partial class MyService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
    {
        public Creds credHeader;  // will hold the creds that are passed in the SOAP Header
    }

    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://cnn.com/xy")]  // your service's namespace goes in quotes
    public class Creds : SoapHeader
    {
        public string Username;
        public string Password;
    }
}
```

And then in the generated proxy class, on the method that calls the service, per J Dudgeon's step 4 add this attribute: `[SoapHeader("credHeader", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]`

finally, here's the call to the generated proxy method, with the header:

```
using (MyService client = new MyService())
{
    client.credHeader = new Creds();
    client.credHeader.Username = "username";
    client.credHeader.Password = "pwd";
    rResponse = client.MyProxyMethodHere();
}
```

Comment: Any chance of providing sample code?  Thanks in advance.  (I'm looking at link/steps, and trying to reconcile his question with his/Dudgeon's sample code, but not directly corresponding/clicking with me on how to translate for security header requirement).

Comment: by the way - this is not a WCF service, probably that's obvious to some

Comment: No need to put more sample code, but please tell me that this code alone didn't get you the Xml format above??  :) I did something 'similar' to this (I had to use PasswordDigest and Nonce) but had to do must more explicit Xml attributing and class structure to get the Xml format I wanted.

Comment: @Terry with my sample code I was able to get the results in user2810857's 2nd block.  that is, the header with the credentials like this: `-<soap:Header>

-<Creds xmlns="http://cnn.com/xy">

<Username>myuser</Username>

<Password>mypwd</Password>

</Creds>

</soap:Header>`

Comment: Works but requires:
`using System.Xml.Serialization;      /*for XmlRoot  */  and 
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;  /*for SoapHeader*/ `